# Запись строки в массивы

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Как пробежаться по строке NSString str=@"11+22*33"; и записать все числа в числовой массив,а все символы в символьный массив???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример того, как можно разложить содержимое строки по двум массивам. Массивы у меня строковые, но если нужно, для получения из строки числа можно сделать

```
int num = [some_string intValue];
```

(либо -doubleValue, -boolValue и [т.д.](http://bit.ly/J625R1)).

---

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (void)
{
    NSString *source = @"11+22*33";

    NSArray *only_digits = [source componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]];
/*
 filteredArrayUsingPredicate: нужен для того, чтобы удалить пустые строки
 из получившегося массива
*/
    only_digits = [only_digits filteredArrayUsingPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != ''"]];

    NSArray *only_chars = [source componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]];
    only_chars = [only_chars filteredArrayUsingPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != ''"]];

    NSLog(@"%@\n%@", only_digits, only_chars);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

регулярки.
([0-9]+) числа
([^123]+) символы

Comment: Какие регулярки?Что это означает?([0-9]+) числа ([^123]+) символы

Comment: регулярные выражения. 
в objective c я не силен вот тут почитать можно
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html